# parameter update in lognormal random generator

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I want to updtade the parameters (mu,sigma) of lognormal random generator from c++ standard library in my code.

```
#include <random>
int main()
{
double mu = 1.0;
double sigma = 0.1;
unsigned seed=(int)( time(NULL) );
std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
std::lognormal_distribution<double> LN_dist(mu,sigma)
double h = LN_dist(generator);
cout << h << endl;
```

The first part is working well. Now I want to update the mu and sigma in the same function (LN_dist) to generate a new random number:

```
mu = 10.0;
sigma = 0.2;
std::lognormal_distribution<double> LN_dist(mu,sigma)
h = LN_dist(generator);
cout << h << endl;
}
```

but it make an error for redeclaration of LN_dist function. If I do not declare it, the output will be with the initial mu and sigma in the first part. Also I can't define a new function, because I have to do it more than 100 times. 
Would you please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about something like `LN_dist = std::lognormal_distribution<double>(mu,sigma);`?

Comment: The for loop is working. But still I can't update  mu and sigma parameters in each loop. My problem is to update the mu and sigma in each loop.

Comment: If I add this part:   
"mu = 10.0;
sigma = 0.2;
std::lognormal_distribution<double> LN_dist(mu,sigma)"   
It make an error for redecleration of ‘std::lognormal_distribution<double> L_dist’.    
If I add only this part:   
"mu = 10.0;
sigma = 0.2;"  
It will use the initial mu and sigma

Answer (score 2):

You can change the parameter distribution using the internal `param_type` and the `param` method. In this case, it would look like:

```
LN_dist.param(std::lognormal_distribution<double>::param_type(10, 0.2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to change values on given object:

```
std::lognormal_distribution<double> LN_dist(mu,sigma)
double h = LN_dist(generator);
LN_dist.m = 10.0;
LN_dist.s = 0.2;
h = LN_dist(generator);

// and so on

    LN_dist.m = 4.0;
    LN_dist.s = 0.6;
    h = LN_dist(generator);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. `m` and `s` are both accessor functions, so it'd need to be `m()` and `s()`, however, both are `const` and return a value, not a reference.